# dkms apport error for Kernel 5.x

Tags: kernel, 19.04, dkms

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here but I have not been able to update my kernel past 4.20.

I've used Ukuu to update my kernels for a while, but when I try to do it with 5.x I receive this error:

```
ERROR (dkms apprt): kernel package linux-headers-5.1.14-050114-generic is not supported
```

After googling I've seen people suggesting this is happening because my secure boot isn't disabled, but I'm positive it is.

I'm verifying it like this:

```
mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode
```

I'm not able to paste the Ukuu log since I can't copy it, but here's screenshots of the installation:
[image]
[image]

Any way to fix this? Can I get a quick explanation of what is going wrong here? Does my hardware just not support this new kernel?

Comment: It looks like Nvidia 418 doesn't like kernel 5.1.14. Download and install a newer Nvidia, then try and upgrade the kernel. Report back.

Comment: Purged nvidia and updated the kernel. Everything seems to work. It's always the fucking nvidia drivers, unbelievable. Thank you so much!

Comment: Try the newer Nvidia drivers. Report back.

Comment: You should probably write an answer not simply add a comment under your question. By providing a detailed information what you did to fix your issue would help many people (including myself :))